# ¿Cómo puedo compilar archivos .Rnw a .pdf desde el archivo Index de un proyecto Bookdwon?

Tags: r, knitr

Anteriormente, he generado múltiples informes en formato .Rnw a .pdf en R a través del comando **knit2pdf()**. Sin embargo, hoy me encuentro con el siguiente problema, lo detallaré por pasos:

1. Estoy construyendo un proyecto con Bookdown.
2. En el archivo Index.Rmd deseo incluir un chunk que llame a un script llamado informes.R, el cual convierte diversos archivo .Rnw a .pdf.
3. Deseo que esto se produzca al momento de presionar "Build Book".
4. Los archivos pdf generados no muestras correctamente los fragmentos de código utilizados en los chunks.
5. Si ejecuto la conversión de manera manual con la opción "Compile PDF" se produce la conversión de manera exitosa.

Como muestra dejo:

1. Llamada al script de R desde el Index.Rmd

```
# Tiene las siguientes opciones el chunk:r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
options(tinytex.engine_args = '-shell-escape') # Minted indent
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
options(kableExtra.html.bsTable = T)
library(gridExtra)

# Controlador para ejecutar archivos .Rnw que generar los talleres en PDF Latex
source("Talleres/informes.R", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

2. Código del archivo informes.R

```
talleres = list.files(path = "Talleres")
talleres = talleres[grepl(".Rnw", talleres)]
lapply(as.list(talleres), function(taller){
  salida = paste("Talleres/",
                 gsub(pattern = ".Rnw", replacement = "", x = taller),
                 ".tex", sep = "")
  taller = paste("Talleres/", taller, sep = "")
  library(knitr)
  knitr::knit2pdf(input = taller, output = salida)
})
```

3. Foto del error

[image: Foto del error]

4. Foto del resultado esperado

[image: Resultado esperado]

La finalidad de esto, es poder generar estos informes e incrustarlos en el documento web.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda :D
PD: primera vez que publico algo, espero haber puesto todo lo necesario.